# ssh issue missing this line in debug result "debug1: channel 0: forcing write"

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

When I performed a remote `ssh` command from a Linux server to Windows one the result command is not emptied to the allocated channel.
The ssh command is :

```
ssh -vvv -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=40 -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no $1 'cmd.exe /c echo 0'||echo 1 2>>$TempPath/$ErrorFile
```

From the  debug of ssh command  I have observed that this line:

```
debug1: channel 0: forcing write
```

it's not present.

Instead this line is present when the same command is performed with succes on another windows server.
From debug ssh log I have also noted that the ssh authentication by  publickey has had succeeded despite this the result is not sent back.
Moreover important thing the the shell script, that contains the loop of  tests of ssh connection, is perfomed by calling an ajax jquery command from a html page.

If the  same script is directly performed from linux prompt command then all windows servers, of the loop, reply correctly to ssh command.
Iinstead this doesn't happen when is runnig from broswer. Take in account that the  "daemon  user" used to run the script from broswer, he is the same used to run the script from prompt command.
I do hope that someone that help me to solve this issue.